# Does the "mapping" tag in hibernate.cfg.xml have an equivalent property name in hibernate.properties?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I thought that hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate.properties were effectively
equivalent, and therefore, could be used interchangeably.  Is this true?

If it is true, then what is the equivalent property name in hibernate.properties
for the "mapping" tag that sometimes appears in hibernate.cfg.xml?

For example, here is an example hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <!-- a SessionFactory instance listed as /jndi/name -->
    <session-factory
        name="java:hibernate/SessionFactory">

        <!-- properties -->
        <property name="connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDB</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">
            org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
        </property>
        <property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:comp/UserTransaction</property>

        <!-- mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/auction/Item.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/auction/Bid.hbm.xml"/>

        <!-- cache settings -->
        <class-cache class="org.hibernate.auction.Item" usage="read-write"/>
        <class-cache class="org.hibernate.auction.Bid" usage="read-only"/>
        <collection-cache collection="org.hibernate.auction.Item.bids" usage="read-write"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I know how to transform some, but not all, tags in this hibernate.cfg.xml to hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.datasource=java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDB
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

But how do you translate the other tags, such as "mapping", to hibernate.properties?

Answer (score 0):

"I thought that hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate.properties were
 effectively equivalent, and therefore, could be used interchangeably.
  Is this true?"

From docs

> An alternative approach to configuration is to specify a full
>   configuration in a file named hibernate.cfg.xml. This file can be used
>   as a replacement for the hibernate.properties file or, if both are
>   present, to override properties.

"mapping" tag

> Class to table mappings are inside the hibernate-mapping tags. In your case I think this should be present in Item.hbm.xml

Yes hibernate.cfg.xml can be translated to equivalent hibernate properties file.

If you do not want to use the mapping tag, you can declare a persistent class using the class element.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.mycompany.sample.domain.Order"/>
        <mapping class="com.mycompany.sample.domain.LineItem"/>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

You can use you can use the [Hibernate Annotations library](https://www.hibernate.org/397.html).

Refer [hibernte-mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-mapping)

Comment: The hibernate specification may say how to resolve situations where both hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate.properties are defined.  That however is not quite what I am asking.  My question is:  can hibernate.cfg.xml be translated into an equivalent hibernate.properties file?